# Jhipster JhiLanguageService always points to relative path

Tags: jhipster, ng2-translate

I am using jhipster application

```
    {
       "generator-jhipster": {
         "promptValues": {
        "packageName": "com.labkit.sci.mycloud",
       "nativeLanguage": "en"
  },
"jhipsterVersion": "5.5.0",
"applicationType": "monolith",
"baseName": "mycloudApp",
"packageName": "com.labkit.sci.mycloud",
"packageFolder": "com/labkit/sci/mycloud",
"serverPort": "8383",
"authenticationType": "oauth2",
"cacheProvider": "no",
"websocket": false,
"databaseType": "sql",
"devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
"prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
"searchEngine": false,
"messageBroker": false,
"serviceDiscoveryType": false,
"buildTool": "gradle",
"enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
"clientFramework": "angularX",
"useSass": true,
"clientPackageManager": "npm",
"testFrameworks": [],
"jhiPrefix": "jhi",
"enableTranslation": true,
"nativeLanguage": "en",
"languages": [
  "en",
  "de"
   ]
 }
}
```

I have configured the SERVER_API_URL in webpack.common.js to

> SERVER_API_URL: `'http://localhost:9000/'`

however the JhiLanguageService is always pointed to relative path

i have also configured in mycloud-app\src\main\webapp\app\app.constants.ts

```
export const SERVER_API_URL = 'http://localhost:9000/';
```

still the url pointing to relative path **http://localhost:9000/site/product/i18n/en.json?buildTimestamp=1540574017051**

however rest of the api calls are  using the SERVER_API_URL, for eg

- http://localhost:9000/management/info
- http://localhost:9000/api/account

is it bug or where do we configure the languageservice path.

Comment: `SERVER_API_URL` is unrelated to your issue.  Are you deploying under a context-path?  What should the URL actually look like?

Comment: Yes the contexts path is http://localhost:9000/site/product/index.html/# because I’m integrating with static sites